# How to add Swashbuckle Swagger documentation to an Azure Mobile Service (not Mobile App Service)

Tags: .net, azure, azure-mobile-services, swagger

How can Swashbuckle Swagger API documentation be added to an Azure Mobile Service with a .NET backend?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** The below answer needs the following mods to enable XML comments once deployed to Azure:
1) Make your generated XML comments part of the project by copying from bin folder to somewhere else and include in the project
2) The XML comments an Embedded Resource 
3) Add the XML comments resource as a custom asset to Swagger like this:

```
c.CustomAsset("commentsxml", thisAssembly , "YOURSERVICE.YOURSUBFOLDER.YOURFILE.xml");
```

4) Change the GetXmlCommentsPath method as follows:

```
  public static string GetXmlCommentsPath()
    {
        return WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["XMLCommentsLocation"];
    }
```

5) Add to web.config the full http url of the new custom asset, eg: http://yoursite:yourport/swagger/ui/commentsxml

---

**UPDATE**
The below does not work for Table controllers. Only for Custom controllers AFAICS

---

After installing the Swashbuckle Nuget package:

```
 Install-Package Swashbuckle
```

into an existing Azure Mobile Services services, the trick is to remove or comment out the following from the SwaggerConfig

```
  public class SwaggerConfig
{


    public static void Register()
    {
        //var thisAssembly = typeof(SwaggerConfig).Assembly;

        //GlobalConfiguration.Configuration 
        //    .EnableSwagger(c =>
        //        {
        // ...
```

and add the .EnableSwagger... stuff onto the config object returned by the mobile service's init code:

```
 public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static string GetXmlCommentsPath()
    {
        return System.String.Format(@"{0}\bin\YOURSERVICENAME.XML", System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
    }
    public static void Register()
    {
        // Use this class to set configuration options for your mobile service
        ConfigOptions options = new ConfigOptions();
        options.LoginProviders.Add(typeof(CustomLoginProvider)); //YOU WILL NOT HAVE THIS IF YOU HAVEN'T ADDED IT

        // Use this class to set WebAPI configuration options
        HttpConfiguration config = ServiceConfig.Initialize(new ConfigBuilder(options));

        config.SetIsHosted(true);

        // To display errors in the browser during development, uncomment the following
        // line. Comment it out again when you deploy your service for production use.
        config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;

        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DefaultValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DefaultValueHandling.Include;  //NOR THIS
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Include;    //NOR THIS


        var thisAssembly = typeof(SwaggerConfig).Assembly;

       // GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
        config
            .EnableSwagger(c =>
            {...
```

Comment: Does this address TableControllers as well? My understanding was that Swashbuckle would not handle the OData querying there.

Comment: To be honest I haven't tried that. Also, I realized that the XML comments part above won't work when deployed to Azure, as the process can't access that filesystem location like that. I am trying to resolve that part now.

Comment: OK I re-added the TodoItem table controller, and yes you are right, it does not get recognized by Swagger.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me by doing

1. In solution explorer, click on Show All Files
2. Navigate to the XML file
3. Right Click on the file and select Publish

This will push that file to Azure and solve this problem. You can include that file in your project (right click => include in project) so it will get pushed to Azure each time you deploy in the future.